# Logging with specific label in log file for every user

Tags: java, servlets, web, log4j

I have web application in Java (JSP + Servlets) and logging with log4j 1.2.17.
When user login on site he take ID. I wanna see all his actions in log file with ID prefix like this:

```
01.05.2015 11:12:30 INFO [Roy] - login correct
```

But i don't want to pass ID in every calling method to logging events in that method.
I want to save ID somewhere and take it when need.

Comment: Simply use the [Mapped Diagnostic Content](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is a [Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html). This effectively gives you a stack of `ThreadLocal` to put data elements into that you can log later.

In java...

```
MDC.put('LOGIN_ID', 'Roy');
```

In your log pattern:

```
"%d %p [%X{LOGIN_ID}] %m
```

Comment: It's important to note that the data needs to be cleaned up correctly using a filter - otherwise there might be data leaks with thread reuse by the container.

Comment: Yes absolutely, you need to clean these up when you are done. You should also never log anything you haven't de-tainted as well.